# Почему в IE11 не работают стили для псевдоэлемента after?

Tags: css

Есть такой код:

```
.exit_popup .close_button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fa5258;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 20;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 1
}

.exit_popup .close_button:after {
    content: '\f00d';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```

В IE11 стили для :after перечеркиваются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто, добавьте свойство `display` и будет Вам счастье. Кстати, псевдоэлементы пишите с двумя двоеточием . Попробуйте следующий код

```
.exit_popup .close_button::after {
    content: '\f00d';
    display: block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```